# How to Get Parent Data Context in Meteor on an Event

Tags: meteor

I'm working on a simple meteor flashcard application. There is a collection of Questions each with: text, right_answer, wrong_answers.

The answers are concatenated into an array and shuffled then the template lays out a question and possible answers. When a user clicks the answer, from the event how do I get the parent data context in the JS.

Something like:

```
<button type="button" question="{{../_id}}" class="btn btn-default answer">
{{this}} {{#with ../this}}{{this._id}}{{/with}}
</button>
```

works to show parent question ID in the template, but how do I do this properly. The goal is to have a function that grabs the event and compares the answer to the "right_answer" for equality and gives you a point if it works. Thanks!

Eventually came up with this solution, but I don't really like it or think it is correct:

```
{{each}}
    {{#with ../this}}
        <button type="button" question="{{../_id}}" class="btn btn-default answer">X</span></button>     
    {{/with}}
    {{this}}
{{/each}}
```

Answer (score 6):

I usually do something like this:

```
Template.myTemplate.answers = function () {
    var self = this;
    // assume that this.answers is a list of possible answers
    return _.map(this.answers, function (answer) {
         return _.extend(answer, {
             questionId: self._id,
         });
    });
}
```

Then you're good to go and in your template you can do things like:

```
<template name="myTemplate">
    {{#each answers}}
        <button data-question="questionId">...</button>
    {{/each}}
</template>
```

**BTW:** Note, that using `question` attribute on `html` element is incorrect according to the standard. You should always prefix your custom tags with `data-`.

Also note, that if you attach events to your templates like this:

```
Template.myTemplate.events({
   'click button': function (event, template) {
       // ...
   },
});
```

then in the event callback you have access to `this`, which represents the context where the `button` element was rendered, as well as `template.data` which is the data context attached to your template instance, so in fact this is more or less your "parent context".

#### EDIT

Note that the new templating engine, i.e. `blaze`, allows us to use dot notation in templates, so the method I described above is no longer needed and `{{../_id}}` is totally fine.

Answer (score 5):

You can access `Template.parentData(n)` in event handlers:  http://docs.meteor.com/#/full/template_parentdata