# Using attribute from "parent"

Tags: meteor

Let's suppose I have `Posts` and `Comments` collections. A `Comment` record contains the attributes `comment` and `postId`. A `Post` record has a `title` attribute.

Now I have a separate page for a single comment (very unlikely irl, but just for the sake of it) where I want to show the comment of course but also the `Post` title. How would I do this, or more in general: how do you reference an attribute from a "parent" (parent between quotes because Mongo is not a referential database)?

One option I often see is to denormalize and also add the `Post` title as attribute to the `Comment` record. Although I do see use cases for denormalization, I am worried about the maintenance nightmare. When the `Post` title gets update, you also need to update them in all other collections where it is used as denormalized attribute.

So, my solution would be to subscribe also to the `Post` on the `Comment` page. Then in `commentDetails.html` I have this:

```
{{post_title}}
```

And in `commentDetails.js` I would have this:

```
Template.commentDetails.helpers({
  post_title: function() {
    return Posts.findOne({_id: this.postId}).title;
  }
});
```

Is this the way to do this?

Edit: clarified the question and updated the example.

Comment: not clear, what you saying ? Can you try explain more or put the more code ?

Comment: Don't be afraid to use `find` on the client. It does not produce any new queries to your original database. It only plays with the data which is already fetched, so the overhead - if any - is only on the client side.

Comment: @John Maybe this will be helpful http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19625940/how-to-get-parent-data-context-in-meteor-on-an-event/19654272#19654272

Comment: I usually use the [`transform` option](http://docs.meteor.com/#/full/mongo_collection) to add a method on the document that returns the doc in the other collection.

Comment: What I read from the documentation is that transform functions are not called reactively, which is not want I want I guess.

Comment: @John, you're referring to the sentence "transform functions are not called reactively"? That means that if you do `theDoc.postTitle = Posts.findOne(this.postId).title`, the postTitle field won't be reactive, but if you instead do `theDoc.postTitle = function(){ return  Posts.findOne(this.postId).title }`, it will be reactive.

Answer (score 0):

After being pointed on Reddit to a [detailed article about this subject](https://www.discovermeteor.com/blog/reactive-joins-in-meteor/), I have implemented as the "naive approach" for now. I am looking into option 4 to make it really reactive.