# Meteor Reactive Nested Object Update Parent Object

Tags: javascript, meteor

I'm trying to make a javascript object reactive such that when a sub-object is updated, the original (parent) object is updated - both in the views and in the javascript.

This almost does it except when the "Done?" button is clicked, the console.log output is only accurate the FIRST time. After that, toggling any sub-items correctly updates the view but the underlying javascript is NOT updated as the "selected" values for the subitems are no longer correct.

Moreover, I'd like to be able to simplify and simply have the parent `items` object update when any sub-items are toggled as selected or not.

I come from AngularJS and this is far simpler - if you pass in an object and then update a property of that object, the parent property is updated as well and kept in sync automatically.

It seems the `this` and data context are getters but not setters? `Template.currentData()` seems related but I haven't been able to get that to work:
https://github.com/meteor/meteor/issues/2010

The way I got the items to update was to manually update it by setting and comparing an index to update the main parent object from the inner sub data context but again that's not ideal and gets messier and messier as you get more nested as I'd need ALL nested indices to be able to back-track up to the main `items` object to then overwrite the whole thing to force an update.
[How to Get Parent Data Context in Meteor on an Event](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19625940/how-to-get-parent-data-context-in-meteor-on-an-event)

Long story short, I want the given data context (from an event) to be able to be a setter such that if I'm in an {{#each }} and happen to be on items[1].subitem[2] then I can just do `this.selected =!this.selected` and that will then effectively update `items[1].subitem[2].selected` (reactively - updating both the javascript object itself and the DOM). So then later I can check the value of `items[1].subitem[2].selected` and know it's reliable and accurate. Currently I'm getting the DOM to update based on the `selected` boolean but the parent `items` array is inaccurate.

HTML / template:

```
<template name="items">
  {{#each items}}
  <div class='item-title'>{{title}}</div>
  <div class='{{classes.cont}}'>
    {{#each subitem}}
      {{> subitems }}
    {{/each}}
  </div>
  {{/each}}

  <div class='btn btn-primary btn-block items-done'>Done?</div>
</template>

<template name="subitems">
  <div class='flexbox subitems'>
    <div class='flex1 pointer'>{{title}}</div>
    {{#if selected}}
    <div class='fa fa-check-circle'></div>
    {{else}}
    <div class='fa fa-plus-circle'></div>
    {{/if}}
  </div>
</template>
```

Javascript

```
if (Meteor.isClient) {
var items1 =[
  {
    title: 'Item 1',
    subitem: [
        {
            title: 'Sub 1.1'
        },
        {
            title: 'Sub 1.2'
        },
        {
            title: 'Sub 1.3'
        }
    ]
},
{
    title: 'Item 2',
    subitem: [
        {
            title: 'Sub 2.1'
        },
        {
            title: 'Sub 2.2'
        },
        {
            title: 'Sub 2.3'
        }
    ]
}
];

var ii, jj;
for(ii =0; ii<items1.length; ii++) {
items1[ii].classes ={
  cont: 'hidden'
};
items1[ii].index =ii;   //Blaze / Spacebars does not yet give access to index? Maybe @index in html but no equivalent in `this` in javascript?

for(jj =0; jj<items1[ii].subitem.length; jj++) {
  items1[ii].subitem[jj].selected =false;
  items1[ii].subitem[jj].index =jj;
}
}

Template.items.created =function() {
  this.items =new ReactiveVar;
  this.items.set(items1);
};

Template.items.helpers({
  items: function() {
    return Template.instance().items.get();
  }
});

Template.items.events({
'click .item-title': function(evt, template) {
var items =template.items.get();
    if(this.classes.cont ==='visible') {
      this.classes.cont ='hidden';
    }
    else {
      this.classes.cont ='visible';
      //hide all others
      for(ii =0; ii<items.length; ii++) {
      if(ii !==this.index) {
        items[ii].classes.cont ='hidden';
      }
    }
    }

    template.items.set(items);
},

  'click .items-done': function(evt, template) {
    console.log(template.items.get());    //TESTING
}

});

Template.subitems.created =function() {
this.selected =new ReactiveVar;
this.selected.set(this.data.selected);
};

Template.subitems.helpers({
selected: function() {
return Template.instance().selected.get();
}
});

Template.subitems.events({
'click .subitems': function(evt, template) {
//toggle selected
this.selected =!this.selected;
template.selected.set(this.selected);
}
});
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Switching to a (local only) collection seemed to make it reactive and I had to indeed update the root (parent) item (using `Template.parentData()`).
So basically converting to and exclusively using as a collection works. A bit annoying and seems a bit like a hack but I suppose that's the point of meteor and blurring the lines between server and client - just use collections for everything and let the built in meteor reactivity work its magic.

https://www.eventedmind.com/feed/meteor-ui-reactivity-in-slow-motion

```
if (Meteor.isClient) {
var items1 =[
{
    title: 'Item 1',
    subitem: [
        {
            title: 'Sub 1.1'
        },
        {
            title: 'Sub 1.2'
        },
        {
            title: 'Sub 1.3'
        }
    ]
},
{
    title: 'Item 2',
    subitem: [
        {
            title: 'Sub 2.1'
        },
        {
            title: 'Sub 2.2'
        },
        {
            title: 'Sub 2.3'
        }
    ]
}
];

var ii, jj;
for(ii =0; ii<items1.length; ii++) {
items1[ii].classes ={
  cont: 'hidden'
};
items1[ii].index =ii;   //Blaze / Spacebars does not yet give access to index? Maybe @index in html but no equivalent in `this` in javascript?

for(jj =0; jj<items1[ii].subitem.length; jj++) {
  items1[ii].subitem[jj].selected =false;
  items1[ii].subitem[jj].index =jj;
}
}

ItemCollection = new Meteor.Collection(null);
for(ii =0; ii<items1.length; ii++) {
ItemCollection.insert(items1[ii]);
}

Template.items.helpers({
items: function() {
return ItemCollection.find();
}
});

Template.items.events({
'click .item-title': function(evt, template) {
var items =ItemCollection.find().fetch();
    if(this.classes.cont ==='visible') {
      this.classes.cont ='hidden';
    }
    else {
      this.classes.cont ='visible';
      //hide all others
      for(ii =0; ii<items.length; ii++) {
      if(ii !==this.index) {
        //items[ii].classes.cont ='hidden';
        ItemCollection.update(items[ii]._id, {$set: {classes: {cont: 'hidden'} } });
      }
    }
    }

    //update current item
    ItemCollection.update(this._id, {$set: {classes: {cont: this.classes.cont } } });
},

'click .items-done': function(evt, template) {
console.log(ItemCollection.find().fetch());    //TESTING
}

});


Template.subitems.events({
'click .subitems': function(evt, template) {
//toggle selected
this.selected =!this.selected;

var itemId =Template.parentData(1)._id;
var setObj ={};
setObj['subitem.'+this.index+'.selected'] =this.selected;
console.log(itemId+' '+JSON.stringify(setObj));   //TESTING
ItemCollection.update(itemId, { $set: setObj});
}
});
}
```

Comment: This [gist](https://gist.github.com/richsilv/7d66269aab3552449a4c) may be of interest.  It's an implementation of a Reactive Object - i.e. an object with a single dependency, but multiple keys (and subkeys), which can be explicitly get or set on their own.

Comment: @user728291 - that link goes to apple developer.

Comment: I think a solution to this is planned but not sure when. Very [detailed discussion here](https://meteor.hackpad.com/Lickable-Forms-and-Components-6CVspZsVwJY#:h=How-it-works). I think your work around is a reasonable approach in the mean time.

Comment: Thanks for the updated link @user728291 - so it seems the key is the `.field()` to set a sub-key and have that propagate up to the top level object?